# Problemas ao salvar valor decimal no Database (Laravel + Postgres)

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Estou usando o Laravel + Postgres e estou esperando receber um valor decimal, e na migration fiz assim: `$table->decimal('valor', 10, 2);`

Quando recebo esse valor, recebo algo do tipo: R$1.500,99
Antes de enviar no banco, fiz um mutator que tira qualquer coisa que NÃO seja número, porém quando chega no postgres chega assim: 150099.00 .
Ou seja, Acrescentou dois zeros no final.

Alguém sabe como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Talvez teu mutator esteja retirando os caracteres que nao sao numeros deixando ele como um inteiro completo

Comment: Você pode utilizar a função https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php

Comment: coloque o mutator na pergunta por favor para verificar o que está fazendo de errado

Comment: Estou chamando essa function no mutator: 


function parse_money($number)
{
    $number = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $number);
    return number_format($number, 2, ',', '.');
}

Comment: primeiro eu to tirando o R$ que chega, e depois formatando mas ainda nao funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você envia da tela: `R$1.500,99` precisa utilizar o [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php) da seguinte forma:

```
function parse_money($number) 
{
    return str_replace(['R$','.',','],['','','.'], $number);
}
```

ou seja, precisa converter para valor decimal referente as configurações do banco.

[Exemplo Online](https://ideone.com/yUdRAV)

<sub>***Ref.*** [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php)</sub>